# How can merge 3 arrays into a single associative array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have 3 arrays, just 7 elements in them each. Arrays are:

`filename[]`

`title[]`

`description[]`

I want to express and iterate through a single associative array for each of the data in the arrays above. `filename` can be the key value for the assoc array, but each filename has it's own corresponding title and description.

Below is a sample of:

```
var_dump($filename)
    string(10) "IMG_1676_3" [1]=> 
    string(10) "IMG_0539_3" [2]=> 
    string(8) "IMG_1942" [3]=> 
    string(8) "IMG_1782" [4]=> 
    string(8) "IMG_2114" [5]=> 
    string(8) "IMG_9759" [6]=> 
    string(8) "IMG_2210" }

var_dump($title)
    string(31) "Lighthouse at Ericeira Portugal" [1]=> 
    string(23) "Gaudi park in Barcelona" [2]=> 
    string(32) "Driving around outside of Lisbon" [3]=> 
    string(16) "Madeira Portugal" [4]=> 
    string(15) "Barcelona Spain" [5]=> 
    string(15) "Lisbon Portugal" [6]=> 
    string(14) "Sailing Lisbon" }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function mergeArrays($filenames, $titles, $descriptions) {
    $result = array();

    foreach ( $filenames as $key=>$name ) {
        $result[] = array( 'filename' => $name, 'title' => $titles[$key], 'descriptions' => $descriptions[ $key ] );
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Just make sure you pass valid input to the function, or add some extra checking. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: How can I call the title or the description of my data field of `$result[0]`?

Comment: `$result[0]['title']` or `$result[0]['description']`

Answer (score 5):

If you array key are the same for all the 3 arrays, the better way to do what you are asking, is a foreach creating a new array with all the key(filename,title,description) in the same key:

```
<?php
foreach($filename as $key => $file)
{
    $files[$key]['filename'] = $file;
    $files[$key]['title'] = $title[$key];
    $files[$key]['description'] = $description[$key];
}
?>
```

Comment: I really like your logic, I think this deserves top answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$result = array_combine($filename, array_map(null, $title, $description));
var_dump($result);
```

Or if you need the inner array to be associative.

```
$result = array_combine($filename, 
  array_map(function($t, $d) { 
      return array('title'=>$t, 'description'=>$d); 
    }, $title, $description
  )
);
```

If you just want to combine the three arrays

```
$result = array_map(function($f, $t, $d) { 
    return array('filename'=>$f, 'title'=>$t, 'description'=>$d); 
  }, $filename, $title, $description
);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$array1 = array("orange", "apple", "grape"); 
$array2 = array("peach", 88, "plumb");
$array3 = array("lemon", 342); 
$newArray = array_merge($array1, $array2, $array3);
foreach ($newArray as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key - <strong>$value</strong> <br />"; 
}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't meet the requirement in the question.